# C++ dynamic array of ints sometimes causes crash

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, crash

I wrote a simple code as follows:

```
void show(const int a[], unsigned elements);

int main()
{
    show(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 45}, 4); //does not work
}

void show(const int a[], unsigned elements)
{
    cout << "{ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
        if (i != elements - 1)
            cout << ",";
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "}";
}
```

It should just output { 1, 2, 3, 45 }. If I include a size in the brackets

```
show(new int[4]{1, 2, 3, 45}, 4);
```

then it works. So naturally I would assume that if I write the `new` this way I have to specify the size (although I thought that giving it an initialization list would imply the size). But, the odd thing is that when set a breakpoint at the show function call and I run it step by step through the debugger, the program outputs everything correctly and terminates at the end of main like it should. If I don't use the debugger, it either crashes after outputting a '{' or it outputs the whole thing "{ 1, 2, 3, 45 }" and an assertion failure " Program: ... "Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) ... "

I'm curious to know why it is behaving this way. Also, I am using Visual Studio on Windows 8.

EDIT: I am `using namepsace std`. Please don't comment about using namespaces or about how to better write this code. I'm solely interested in the cause of this issue.

Comment: The first problem is your use of a "dynamic array", doing `new` like that might very likely cause a memory leak.  When you thing "dynamic array" your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The return value of `new T[]` is `T *`, NOT `T[]`. This looks like something a person with Java background would write.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand that, and I wouldn't normally use it that way or I would at least make sure to delete the memory, but I was just wondering why it acts this way.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli I actually do have a java background, but from my understanding, you can pass in a pointer to the first element of a dynamically allocated array as an argument where they type specified is an array. Also, this is not the cause of the issue, because if I specify the size of the array, it works just fine.

Comment: I'd still advice you to use `std::vector`. If you have a C++11 capable compiler, and you change `show` to take a constant vector reference as argument, writing e.g. `show({1, 2, 3, 45})` would "just work".

Comment: It behaves that way because `new int[]` does not create an array of 4 int.    From memory, such code should not even compile according to the standard, since it is initialising something that is not an array of 4 elements (the result of `new int []`) with an initialiser that consists of 4 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Responding to additional question in comment.

To be quick, yes it would "still" be a pointer, and yes it compiles with clang and gcc when you add the 4.

There are a couple things going on, however, and my initial answer was a simplification. The problem is that your expression is not well-formed to begin with, so it's not clear what it should evaluate to or what the type should be. Consider

> If type is an array type, all dimensions other than the first must be specified as positive integral constant expression (until C++14)converted constant expression of type std::size_t (since C++14), but the first dimension may be any expression convertible to std::size_t.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

As it says, either way there must be an expression in the brackets. This makes it difficult to say whether the expression would *still* evaluate to a pointer. A well-formed `new` expression would indeed evaluate to a pointer, no matter how many dimensions it has, even if it has zero. When I say pointer here, I strictly mean the representation, not the type.

The point is that the type, at least "inside" `new`, is different depending on how many dimensions you have. So, whether you do

```
new int
new int[6]
new int[12][14]
```

the representation is the same (a pointer), but the type `new` sees is different in each case. The compiler is able to respond to the different types in `new` (think by analogy with function overloading). In particular, when the type is an array type, it is possible to initialize the new memory with the braced initializer list containing multiple elements.

My best guess is, since VS was accepting the brackets without an expression, it was allocating memory for either a single `int` or `int[0]`. In the former case, it was wrongly allowing you to brace initialize it as if it was an array type, and in the latter case the allocated memory was not enough anyway. Your `main` then wrote over a heap guard that is there to catch this sort of thing in debug mode. When this was checked at the end of `main` or at program termination, you saw the symptoms. The flakiness in the output was either due to different heap layouts or due to buffering in the output stream.

**Original answer**

Your `new` expression, if it was well-formed, would have scalar type, meaning that the result is a "single value". That single value is a pointer to an integer, specifically to the one at the beginning of the array you are trying to create. That is how "dynamic arrays" are represented in C++. The type system does not "know" their size.

You are trying to initialize this single pointer value with an initializer list of 4 values. This shouldn't work. I am not sure that this should compile at all. It certainly didn't compile with clang or gcc, and I'm surprised that it worked in Visual Studio.

Comment: Interesting, but then why does it work if I put the 4 inside the brackets? The expression would still evaluate to a pointer to a single value, correct? Does it compile with gcc or clang if you add the 4 into the brackets?

Comment: Thank you. This is the kind of explanation I was looking for.